# param : implicit EL (Expression Language) object in JSP

Tags: jsp, el

What if I have URL like: `servlet.jsp?myparam=myvalue`

These 2 ELs should return output **"myvalue"** , but I actually don't understand why?:

```
${param.values["myparam"]["0"]}
${param.values.myparam[0]}
```

Answer (score 21):

Where did you get this information from? This won't work in standard JSP 2.1 EL. The correct syntax would be:

```
${param["myparam"]}
${param.myparam}
```

In the first example, singlequotes are also allowed and actually more preferred.

```
${param['myparam']}
```

It can even be another EL variable in any scope:

```
${param[myparam]}
```

Actually, the `${param}` refers to a `Map<String, String>` with only the first param value from the array. In *theory*, if it was a `Map<String, String[]>` and the `Map` class had a `getValues()` method, then your syntax should work. But it doesn't have, it only has a `values()` method. Your best bet would then be using `${paramValues}` instead which refers to a `Map<String, String[]>`:

```
${paramValues['myparam'][0]}
${paramValues.myparam[0]}
```

or accessing the [`HttpServletRequest#getParameterMap()`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterMap%28%29) directly:

```
${pageContext.request.parameterMap['myparam'][0]}
${pageContext.request.parameterMap.myparam[0]}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I thought so. 
This is actually one "correct" answer from uCertify prepEngine software for SCWCD. I just wanted to be sure and hear some opinions.